# In CQ5, how do I configure a dropdown in an extJS component?

Tags: extjs, aem

I am registering a xtype which requires a text field and dropdown.
for Text field we give the xtype of Cq widget as:

```
this.linkText = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField
```

What would we need to write in ExtJs for dropdown?

Answer (score 2):

You can write drop down like -

```
var cb = new CQ.Ext.form.ComboBox({
    // all of your config options
    listeners:{
         scope: yourScope,
         'select': yourFunction
    }
});
```

for more help -

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.ComboBox